# php - Extract an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I am trying to extract a mixed associative array like:

```
<pre>
        <?php


        bar();

        function bar(){
            $apple = 6;
            $ball = 2;
            $cat = 3;

            $data = ["apple" => 1, $ball,$cat];

            foo($data);
        }

        function foo($data){
            extract($data);
            echo "<br />apple:" . $apple;
            echo "<br />ball:" . $ball;
            echo "<br />cat:" .  $cat;
        }

        ?>
</pre>
```

**The `$data` array can be only numeric, only associative or both. If element of array misses an index, it should be same as the variable.**

Comment: @Andrew, No. Array can sometimes only associate or numeric. They are mixed to any level.

Comment: `$ball` and `$cat` are defined in scope (before extract) and thus they still exist. This is why they do not work in function. The Array has no index to assign to the variable when running extract. .

Comment: RTFM -> extract creates variables using the keys as variable names, and the values as... erm... values. In your first snippet, it just so happens that `$cat` and `$ball` have the same value as keys `0` and `1` in the array, but `extract` is actually skipping the numeric indexes

Comment: If it's not scope, that means your data is bad to use for `extract()`. Iterate your Array and collect the data manually into variable instead of using `extract()` to ensure you get the values.

Comment: @tika Why must there be numeric keys ? Can't you force the array to be as you wish ? How will you know that $data[0] is the value of $ball if the name is not in the key ? If you have no control on `$data`, you may have to get a mapping array, saying what is the variable order expected... in order to say "1st value is APPLE, 2nd will be BALL, and 3rd will be CAT"... and then use this mapping array to extract data manually...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not work in your function because $ball and $cat are not defined in the function scope. The extract() function will only assign the value to a variable if the value in the array has a key, which $apple does. This means that $apple will output in the function, but $ball and $cat would be undefined.

This happens because in order for extract() to know what to name the variable, there has to be a key in the array.

To do this, you either need to manually specify the keys in the array each time:

```
$apple = 6;
$ball = 2;
$cat = 3;
$data = ["apple" => $apple, "ball" => $ball, "cat" => $cat];

// Now, extracting from $data creates the variables we need...
// Unsetting the $apple, $ball, and $cat variables 
// allows us to see that extract is recreating them.
unset($apple, $ball, $cat);
extract($data);
echo $apple, $ball, $cat;
```

Or you need to check the $ball and $cat variables to see if they are arrays. If they are arrays, you could use their key in the array so that extract() knows what to name the variable it creates. Do you need to dynamically determine if a variable already has a key (is an array), or is this enough?

EDIT: This should not be done with extract(). Realistically, you should create a class and store this data within a class. Then, loading the class would give you this information. extract() is a dangerous and messy beast.

Comment: Good point to unset variables, to understand what happens... ! Without "ball" and "cat" keys in $data, this code wouldn't work !

Comment: @Random: Not unless you prefix the values you're `extract`-ing

Comment: @MikelBitson, the data is mixed array and will be.

Comment: @tika Do you understand why you'll never get a variable $ball out of an array that doesn't ever have the word "ball" in it? If the data is mixed, we need to see what format the data is coming in to determine how we can add that key. The key HAS* to be added for extract to work. So- if the key is coming with the $ball var we need to see how that will be formatted to correctly add it to the $data array in a way that will give us the "ball" key. Check your variable with is_array() and depending on the return, manually add the key or use the key from the variable.

Comment: @MikelBitson, Oh yeah. I now get it. It's quite `impossible.`

Comment: @tika Not impossible, if you always want to use the variable name when the variable is just numeric, simply check to see if the variable is numeric (is_numeric()) and manually add the key when it is. Either way, the key has to be there.

Comment: @MikelBitson, Yes but. Let's say, no changes can be done to `function bar()`. I am in charge of `foo()`. :(

Comment: @tika If you absolutely can not change the bar() function, can you assume that the order they're added to the array will always be the same? In that case you could create a reference array in your function and manually assume the keys based on ordering. If the ordering may change than this is not an option and you simply can not extract the variable name without adding it. This can be done like Twisty pointed out in his answer- simply reference the index within the array and create your own variables.

Comment: @tika Did this work for you? Is another answer more applicable to your initial question? Remember to vote and pick answers.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer. The point is still the same, if you have an Array of mixed content, don't use `extract()`.

```
function foo($data){
    extract($data);
    echo "<br />apple:" . (isset($apple)?$apple:$data[0]);
    echo "<br />ball:" . (isset($ball)?$ball:$data[1]);
    echo "<br />cat:" .  (isset($cat)?$cat:$data[2]);
}
```

You can see the pitfalls here. If data has more or less indexes, or the order is not correct, you will get a failed index or incorrect value.

Comment: Problem is I have no idea what is coming, apple, ball, plane ... :(

Comment: Any way to format the data? How is the data being presented to you?